# Get current page url from included php file?

Tags: php, url, include

I have a page that is index.php that includes script.php, and in script.php I have it echo the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];` and when it echos it on index.php it shows the url of script.php. I need to keep this function in the script.php but want index.php to show. Isn't it that include only attaches that code in index.php so it should run on there, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the reason is that I was doing the include using an http request li`include 'http://www.mysite.com/script.php';` instead I should have done  `include 'script.php';` and gotten the local file.